# How to normalize a complex json format in a pandas data frame that is a list of dictionaries

Tags: python, pandas, eval

I have a pandas data frame that has one column like this in json format. I am not able to understand how to extract this.

```
df['completionDetails'][0] gives:

[{'name': 'start', 'time': 1654098788177},
 {'name': 'arrival',
  'time': 1654099038368,
  'location': [-74.2713929, 40.5017297]},
 {'name': 'departure',
  'time': 1654098843357,
  'location': [-74.2802414, 40.5095964]}]
```

I have tried:

```
dict_df = pd.DataFrame([ast.literal_eval(i) for i in df['completionDetails'].values])
```

But it is giving me error. What method can I use for this?

Expected Output:

```html
start_time  arrival_time    arrival_location    departure_time  departure_location
1654098788177   1654099038368   [-74.2713929, 40.5017297]   1654098843357    [-74.2802414, 40.5095964]
```

Comment: What is the outcome supposed to look like?

Comment: I am really not able to understand this format. But given this scenario columns should be like start_time, arrival_time, arrival_location, departure_time, departure_location..

Comment: That is not json - it's a dict.

Comment: But how to extract this in data frame as separate columns?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IIUC each cell of the `completionDetails` column is a list of dictionaries.
You can make a dataframe out of each cell and concatenate the dfs:

```
dict_df = pd.concat([pd.DataFrame(i) for i in df['completionDetails'].values])
```

###### Edit:

Following your own edit, this is how you'd get the desired output:

```
dict_df = pd.concat([pd.DataFrame({f"{x['name']}_{k}": [v]
                          for x in i for k,v in x.items() if k!='name'}
                          ) for i in df['completionDetails'].values if isinstance(i, list)])
```

As you can see we're building key names from the `name` key and other keys to create new dictionaries that will be used to create dataframes (that in turn will be concatenated to each other)

Output:

```
      start_time   arrival_time           arrival_location  departure_time         departure_location
0  1654098788177  1654099038368  [-74.2713929, 40.5017297]   1654098843357  [-74.2802414, 40.5095964]
```

Comment: But it will give me 3 rows for each..

Comment: what is your expected output?

Comment: Hi, I have updated my question with expected output. If you look closely, what I have provided is just one row of the column. Actually its the 0th element, and here key is provided as a value in this format

Comment: I've edited my answer, check it out!

Comment: Thank you for quick edits.. but now it says float object is not iterable..

Comment: I guess some rows of `completionDetails` are floats?  You can exclude them (updated my answer again)